# how to check the Database URL in oDoo

Tags: odoo, ubuntu-18.04, nginx-reverse-proxy

i have installed oDoo with nginx on ubuntu 18.04.2 and create the multiple databases.
i want to check/see the database URL,is that possible? if possible the then which things i needed to see the database URL.
if have any plugin or third party solution to check the database URL then please mention here.

Comment: What do you mean by database URL?

Comment: You get your web URL by the system parameter as "web.base.url"

Comment: i want to access the user database with url

Answer (score 1):

You can access the database with url as **your_odoo_instance/web?db=your_db_name**.

Eg: www.example.com/web?db=customer_db.

It will redirect to the login screen of the db `customer_db`.

Comment: one more question i want see the user DB,can we use any plugin for it?

Comment: Sorry i don't get you.